# Reading XML File from Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, nsbundle

I'm currently parsing an XML file that resides in my bundle using NSXMLParser with the following line:

```
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"XMLFileName" ofType:@"xml"]];
```

But I want to put the same file on my server instead. I can't find an example of how to call the same file from my server. Any help is appreciated. 
lq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURL` has several methods for creating URLs, one of which is `-URLWithString:`; like so:

```
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/example.xml"];
```

That URL can be passed directly to `NSXMLParser`; but you might want to do so in a secondary thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to HTTP GET the file from your server then you should look at `NSURLConnection`. It allows you to do synchronous or asynchronous HTTP requests.